# SQL Server nested table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Persons: theoretically, unlimited number of persons can be registered in the system. Contact information linked to each person should also be able to be added without limits.

- UUID
- Name
- Surname
- Company

Communication information:

- Information Type: Telephone Number, E-mail Address, Location
- Information Content

Report:

- Location information

  - Most -> Least to be listed by their number of locations
- The number of people registered in the directory at that location
- Number of phone numbers registered in the phone book at that location

I have 2 tables, how should the relationship be between them and I am confused since the Communication information attribute has 2 attributes in itself. Should communication information be in a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to divide this into three tables:

- Persons(UUID,Name,Surname,Company)
- CommunicationType(Telephone Number, E-mail Address,)
- CommunicationInformation(Person_ID,CommunicationType_ID, ......)